# Очень странная ошибка с импортом js gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, импорт, package.json

Всё начиналось с того что я собирал gulp по гайду, всё было отлично, собрал, но на следующий день при запуске летит в лицо это [image: не импортирует сам gulp].
type стоит "module", с этим всё нормально.

Причём вчера запускалось всё на ура, единственное закинул на github https://github.com/fedyaka/gulpTemplate , можете посмотреть пожалуйста, там очень много комментов, но даже такой разбор кода не помогает.

Что я пробовал:

1. Перезагрузить комп(очень надеялся что поможет)
2. Переустановка всех модулей
3. Переустановака gulp-cli -g
4. Переустановка Node.js
5. Пытался разобрать код по частям проверяя что может не работать
6. Устанавливал по частям все зависимости, наблюдая что что нибудь вылезет, но нет.

Comment: Единственное кстати, я пытался в проекте работать с React и прикрутить Babel, до этого я не пробовал запускать сегодня

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ребят расходимся, я идиот, нужно было просто убрать {}, однако из 12 просмотров никто этого не заметил...